# Multiple SET fields using LOAD DATA INFILE for Date Format

Tags: php, mysql

I am able to use LOAD DATA INFILE to successfully get my csv file uploaded. I am able to skip all of the data/columns that I don't need ([Manual 13.2.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html))

I was able to use the SET command to set the date format. My question is, What if I have multiple Date fields, any variation of the SET command combined with the above doesn't want to work when I have more than 1 SET.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['load']))
{
include '_inc/include.php'; 

$temp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$sqlstatement="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$temp' INTO TABLE 000_1616 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (id, @somedate, name, anotherdate, color, 1moredate) SET sdate = IF(LENGTH(@somedate)=7,STR_TO_DATE(@somedate,'%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(@somedate,'%m/%d/%y'))";
mysql_query($sqlstatement) or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "It worked";
echo "<p><a href='upload-display.php'>go to page</a></p>";
} 

?>

<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="myfile" type="file" />
<input name="load" type="submit" value="submit" /></form>
```

My SET goes Like This

```
SET sdate = IF(LENGTH(@somedate)=7,STR_TO_DATE(@somedate,'%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(@somedate,'%m/%d/%y'))";
```

or

```
$sqlstatement="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$temp' INTO TABLE 000_1616 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (id, @somedate, name, anotherdate, color, 1moredate) SET sdate = IF(LENGTH(@somedate)=7,STR_TO_DATE(@somedate,'%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(@somedate,'%m/%d/%y'))";
```

I used @somedate for the first date field Which is really sdate. This works well so long as I don't try to add 4 more date fields using SET. I would like to add @anotherdate (anotherdate) and @1moredate(1moredate) Do I have to set up an array? Do I need to do something in the Table on the phpMyADMIN side? Right now they are formatted to Date but they all come back 000-00-00 except for the first date filed.

Here is the SQL:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `database_track`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `000_datetest`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `000_datetest` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `sdate` date default NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `anotherdate` date NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(50) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `1moredate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

csv example:

```
+----+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+
| id | sdate          | name             | anotherdate     | color        | 1moredate     |
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------------+
|  1 | 2011-08-21 | Tom Thumb |    08/16/2010     |   Blue     | 1/5/08            |
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------------+
|  1 | 2009-05-12 | Don Duck      |    03/22/2012     |   Yellow   | 9/15/03       |
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I hope this helps, Please see physical file in comment below

Comment: Can you provide table structure - CREATE TABLE statement, and example of CSV file?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure how to upload it here. Go to this Link: http://muldoon.cc/010203/ You can test the form and or download the ZIP or all of the files individually

Comment: It is not a CSV file, it is simple text file with data. You should skip every odd record, but LOAD DATA INFILE cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple SET commands with LOAD DATA INFILE you only need to specify SET once and separate each variable definition with commas eg.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'my_file' INTO TABLE 'my_table' (column1, @date1, @date2)
SET column2 = STR_TO_DATE(@date1, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'),
column3 = STR_TO_DATE(@date2, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```