# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - Date Issue with Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a novice developer and only use PHP/Mysql to load data and then use PowerBI for my data analysis.

I'm trying to update a CSV using the following command:

```
mysqli_query($cons, '
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file1.'"
INTO TABLE '.$table.'
FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'        
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

My data has date in the following format:
13-Jul-17

When it gets added to the MySQL database, I get the following issue:

```
Date        Campaign
"13 Jun     2017"
```

So I want to know, why is the date being broken and going into 2 columns. How can I fix this.

Also I have some extra characters in some columns, is there any way to remove those characters during the query to be updated:
Example:
â‚¬0.08

Can I remove â‚¬ within the query so it doesn't get added?

Comment: I highly doubt your input is in the format `13-Jul-17`. I am pretty sure it is in the format `"13 Jul, 2017"`. You will have to use `FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` to make the import ignore the `,`. Also be aware that your `date`-field is a varchar, not a datetime field. To modify your input during import (e.g. remove specific characters), you can use `set`, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866893/multiple-set-fields-using-load-data-infile-for-date-format). You can use this too to convert your date-string to a datetime value (which has to be in the format YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I verified. The data is:
13-Jul-17
13-Jul-17
13-Jul-17
13-Jul-17
13-Jul-17

Comment: Also can you give an example in my case on how to use SET to remove characters. That would help alot!

Comment: Well, at least in one occasion, it is `"13 Jun, 2017"`. Otherwise it wouldn't be read as the two seperate strings `"13 Jun` and `2017"` (seperated by a comma). If your csv data is not well defined (e.g. has a different format in some rows), it gets a lot more complicated. You can use [`replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) and the syntax in my last link to remove parts of a string, e.g. `replace('â‚¬0.08', 'â‚¬', '')` (although it might also be a charset problem, as `â‚¬` is utf8 `€`, so you might have to read/write your data in utf8).

Comment: I changed the coloumn in Mysql to UTF8 Unicode and its now coming as € which is good. No need to change this.

My main problem now is Date. I checked and there is no other format.

Comment: Is every date incorrect or just some? What happens in rows where you have already verified that you have `13-Jul-17` in your input file? You should open the file in an editor and search for `"13 Jun, 2017"` (or, in case there are special characters in it, `Jun,`, although it might find other stuff too first).